# glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH) explanation?

Tags: c++, c, glut

I' working on some OpenGl tutorials using Glut and I come across

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH)
```

I understand what it does but what I don't understand is how it does it?

Looking at the definitions :

```
GLUT_DOUBLE                        0x0002
GLUT_RGB                           0x0000
GLUT_DEPTH                         0x0010
```

and I can see that there is a OR bit wise operation in the functions' arguments.

How does this bitwise operation work on the macros above ? What are the values that they represent, physical address from the memory?

Right now I'm just displaying some shapes that rotate in a 400x400 px window, and disabling any of that arguments did not seem to have any visual effect.

Thanks!

Comment: It might help to convert the hex representation of the numbers involved into binary. Calculating the result of the OR operation is straightforward from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two of those constants, `GLUT_DOUBLE` and `GLUT_DEPTH`, each contain one set bit:

```
GLUT_DOUBLE = 0x0002 = 0b0000 0000 0000 0010
GLUT_DEPTH  = 0x0010 = 0b0000 0000 0001 0000
```

Combining those constants with a bitwise OR creates a new value with both of those bits set, and it's possible to check whether those bits are set in the resulting value using e.g.

```
if ((display_mode & GLUT_DOUBLE) != 0) { ... }
```

`GLUT_RGB` is zero. Including it has no effect on the result; I suspect it represents a setting that is true by default.

The specific numbers used don't have any deeper significance. They're just used as a way of combining a bunch of on/off options in a single integer argument.

Comment: Thanks for that!  The thing with the numbers was really confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

As for the meaning of the flags, check the docs for [glutInitDisplayMode()](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node12.html). In particular,

> GLUT_DOUBLE
>
> Bit mask to select a double buffered window. This overrides GLUT_SINGLE if it is also specified.
>
> GLUT_DEPTH
>
> Bit mask to select a window with a depth buffer.

Double buffering will make your animation much smoother. For a simple program, you probably won't see much difference between single and double buffering. For more complex animations, the difference is significant.

The depth buffer is important for 3D graphics.

I suggest doing some research if you wish to understand how these work in more detail.